# Unable to create database in my android app

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I would like to create an application with a SQLite database but I do not know why I can not create the database

```
class Db_Connection(context: Context?) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context,"my_db",null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        var create_Table =
            "Create Table product( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,  name TEXT)"
        p0!!.execSQL(create_Table)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    }
```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Db_Connection(this)
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? Are you getting any errors or Exceptions?

Comment: i didn't get any thing

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, then. How are you determining that you "can not create the database"?

Comment: Are you trying to find the database file after running that code? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes  ,I did not find Device Folder Database in File Explorer> Data->Data->my BackageName

Comment: Just instantiating your `SQLiteOpenHelper` doesn't cause the database to be created. You actually have to use it first; e.g., by accessing `writeableDatabase` or `readableDatabase`.

Answer (score -1):

Well this is java based code. Hope it can help you a bit

Create a database class and extends it to SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Constants {
private static final String dbname = "towers.db";
private static final int dbversion = 1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 //  String query = "CREATE TABLE TOWERS_TABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINICREMENT, CIRCLE TEXT, OPERATOR TEXT, NETWORK TEXT, CELLID TEXT, SIGNAL_STRENGTH TEXT)";
    String query =  "CREATE TABLE TOWERS (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINICREMENT, DATA TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(query);

}

public void insertData(String data, SQLiteDatabase database){
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("data",data);
        database.insert("TOWERS",null,values);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void clearData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TOWERS";
    db.execSQL(query);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Now create an object of database class where you want to add value

```
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 databaseHelper.insertData(data,database); //Here data is the value that you want to store
```